# Size/Resize Containers Labels and Buttons in CN1

Tags: java, button, label, size, codenameone

i have difficulties in resizing elements in CN1, f.e. i want to resize a Button and put an image on it to use in a MenuBar, the Buttons are too big so that it exceeds the space of a Samsung S5 Display. Im working with the Designer and tried a lot with the Themes/Styles but dont seem to find a solution for this.

The MenuBar as in the screen has too large buttons, the left one is the Logo of the Company, the Buttons are three in total but only two can be seen..

For the yellow status icon, same problem same hassle :\

Do i really have to manage this in source code or is there a more convenient way with the UIDesigner.[image]

Regards

**EDIT :** i now found out that using "icon" in the Designer is rubbish. Instead use this following Trick.
Put in a Text, define a Style in the ThemeEditor, set Font-Size in millimeters. Also set the Background Image and its behaviour to ScaleToFit, it should Resize now. Only Downside i have using this technique is that i have to use Whitespaces instead of a Text, is this really the best practice or does someone have a better approach?

Also another downside is that for every Image you have to Design a single Style

Answer (score 1):

In order to support multi DPI's the icon needs to adjust it's size to the many screen sizes available.
Use multi-image https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage.html

Comment: I saw this video already a while ago, my images are already imported as a multiimage.

Still the question remains, i think there is not a way to do this via GUI Designer. Also no one else posted an idea until yet. So i think i have to go the Image.scaled() route where i wanted to avoid that.

Comment: If you use multi-image and the icons you get are too big, just open the multi image in the designer and adjust it's sizes to smaller sizes for each resolution

Comment: I am doing something totally wrong in this case, there is that "Scale" button, when i press it and put in the values for width and height, click on "OK" ,nothing happens?

Comment: The UE of the designer might be confusing, when you do scale you are scaling from 1 dpi to another dpi, so if the multi image DPI combo is currently showing on "HD up To 1920x1080" and you press on scale you will need to select the target DPI in the To combo.(The current DPI cannot be selected only a different DPI).

Comment: Thank you, indeed its a bit confusing =)

What can you say to my approach about the labeling technique with an empty String instead of using the icon field of the Labels/Buttons?

And regarding the Size of Cells, is it correct that the only way to manage this is to use TableLayouts?

Comment: I understands why it works for you but I don't think it's the right thing to do,  just adjust the multi image to better dimensions for each of the DPI's and it will start working for you

Comment: Alternatively when you use "quick add multi images" select a more correct base resolution. If the images are too big select a higher base DPI like HD. If they are too small select a lower base DPI like High.